# run command line (cmd) that require "Security Message"

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, driver

I want to run the command line `pnputil` in c# program. The program needs to install USB driver.
I know how to run cmd in c# program, but I have a different problem:

**The driver that I want to install does't have permission of windows.**

If I Install the driver via the "device manager->update driver" and choose the path of the driver, I get "Security Message" from windows that "windows can't verify the publisher of this drive software" and let me choose if install the driver or not (of course, if I choose to install - the installing succeeds).

If I run the command from the cmd `pnputil -a <path_name_inf>` I get this message too and I can install the driver.

But when I try to run the command via c# program - the program runs but the driver is not installed (I also don't get this message).

my code in c#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C Pnputil -a <path_name_inf>";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Your software is giving you a security massage? Where can I get this wondrous thing? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run the *cmd* using the `runas` verb:

```
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

This parameter causes a privileges elevation. The same thing could be reached when you use *"Run as administrator"* in explorer.

Comment: @user1994587 if you share that *Security Message*, it'll speed up finding the solution.

Comment: psst. that's `still` not `steel`, and `message` not `massage`. `Massage` is applying pressure on the skin/body, that's why DavidG joked about that in the comments.

Comment: Also, [when you say that something didn't work, you have to say _how_ it didn't work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/21/9999675.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is more towards installing unsigned drivers.

Can you please try following steps: 
Open a command prompt as an admin and type:

```
bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Please refer [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484(v=vs.85).aspx) for more infromation on Test Signing. Making Test signing may put a watermark as TEST in desktop waterpaper

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I wanted to share my solution in case it can help someone else.

My specific scenario is that I wanted to add an unsigned driver package to the driver store on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Like the OP, this worked as expected (meaning I received the security warning and the driver package was added to the driver store) if I executed `pnputil -a <path_to_inf>` using a command prompt using "Run as administrator".

[image: Windows can't verify the publisher of this driver software]

However, if I tried to call pnputil from within C#, I was never able to get the security warning and the driver package was not added to the driver store. I had tried using various options (i.e. Verb = "runas", UseShellExecute = true, etc) with the FileName set as "pnputil" or "cmd".

Ultimately, what worked for me was to create a simple batch file that contained the following:

```
%windir%\sysnative\pnputil /a <path_to_inf>
```

My C# app would then call this batch file as follows:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "<path_to_bat_file>";
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
```

The user would first be prompted because I asked to run with elevated permission followed by the expected security warning. The driver package would then be added to the driver store as expected.

[image: User Account Control]

If this does not work as expected, you can add "pause" (without quotes) on a new line after the last command in the batch file and remove the WindowStyle and CreateNoWindow lines from the C# code to see what is happening on the command prompt.